# Notification only when user is awake

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

I have a water reminder application, I want the notificaiton to appear only when the user is not sleeping as there is no point in showing notifications when the user is sleeping as they can't drink water while sleeping so I want to skip notification during that time, I have the user's sleep and wake time, and this is my code to handle notifications but the notifications are still shown bypassing the logic here.

```kotlin
class NeerNotificationService(
    private val context: Context
) : NeerNotification {

    private val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    override fun showNotification(notificationItem: NotificationItem) {
        val currentTime = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)
        val userSleepTime =  PreferencesManager(context).getSleepCycleTime(SleepCycle.SLEEP_TIME)
        val userWakeTime = PreferencesManager(context).getSleepCycleTime(SleepCycle.WAKE_TIME)
        Timber.d("User sleep time, wake time and current time")
        Timber.d(userSleepTime.toString())
        Timber.d(userWakeTime.toString())
        Timber.d(currentTime.toString())

        if (currentTime.isAfter(userSleepTime) && currentTime.isBefore(userWakeTime)) {
            Timber.d("Skipping notification")
            return
        }
            Timber.d("Showing notification")
            val activityIntent = Intent(context, NeerActivity::class.java)
            val activityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                1,
                activityIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )
            val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, WATER_REMINDER_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_outline_water_bottle)
                .setContentTitle(notificationItem.title)
                .setContentText(notificationItem.message)
                .setContentIntent(activityPendingIntent)
                .build()

            notificationManager.notify(1, notification)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use the or condition

```
if (currentTime.isAfter(userSleepTime) || currentTime.isBefore(userWakeTime))
```

Comment: It works, Thanks! but could you please tell the thinking behind it, as my logic in question also seems to be valid?

Comment: you can read whether the current time > sleep time or the current time < wake up time